# nginx error upgrading web server from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, apache2, nginx

I'm running nginx as a reverse proxy to apache. I'm upgrading ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04 but getting this after a failed `apt-get dist-upgrade` and running `apt-get -f install`

```
After this operation, 2,426 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 95519 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nginx_1.11.3-1~wily_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx (1.11.3-1~wily) over (1.10.0-0+wily0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.11.3-1~wily_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/logrotate.d/nginx', which is also in package nginx-common 1.10.1-0+wily0
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.11.3-1~wily_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mix and match nginx.org repos and the Ubuntu PPAs for NGINX.  You are trying to use two separate PPAs - 1.11.3 from upstream Mainline repos, and 1.10.0 from my NGINX Stable PPA. This is something I touched upon in my blog post [here, when an influx of bugs prompted the notice](http://dark-net.net/?p=80).  (Content copied into below)

Pick one repo, and drop the other in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` sources.  Remove the older packages if you have them.  (Upstream Mainline repo will break the PPA, so you have to remove `nginx-common`, `nginx-core`, `nginx-full`, `nginx-extras`, `nginx-light` and `nginx` before you can install upstream's newer version.

(There is a PPA update going out in the next few days for the Mainline PPA containing 1.11.3)

---

Content of the blog post linked above:

> ## NGINX: Mixing and Matching Ubuntu Repositories (and NGINX team PPAs on Launchpad) or Debian Repositories with Upstream Repositories will result in problems.
>
> We’ve seen this before, but we see it too frequently. People want the
>   latest NGINX version. So they use the upstream nginx.org repository to
>   get it. They try and install, and you immediately get conflicts.
>
> In Ubuntu, people then file bugs on this thinking it’s an Ubuntu issue
>   (such as [this bug here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1440363)). Problem is, it’s not an Ubuntu bug. Nor
>   is it a bug in the PPAs I maintain. Nor is it a bug in Debian. It’s a
>   problem that arises when you mix the upstream repositories and either
>   Ubuntu, Debian, or the Ubuntu PPAs, and assuming you can ‘upgrade’
>   cleanly with the upstream repositories.
>
> Basically, this is what it comes down to:
>
> **For Debian, if you’re depending on third party modules, you should stick to Debian’s packaging and wait. For Ubuntu, you should use the
>   PPAs which I maintain (under the nginx team on Launchpad) if you want
>   latest software and features, based off of Debian’s packaging
>   decisions.**
>
> **If you want/depend on NAXSI though, you have no choice but to recompile NGINX with NAXSI yourself, in order to get it working in a
>   sane way. Neither Debian, nor Ubuntu, nor the PPAs have naxsi in the
>   builds anymore.**
>
> **If none of those apply to you, you will have to purge all nginx binaries from your computer, and all nginx packages and configuration
>   files with this command before installing from the upstream
>   repository: `sudo apt-get purge nginx nginx-doc nginx-common` (This
>   should also purge the other dependent packages as well)**
>
> But, if you’re curious why you can’t mix the repositories, this post
>   explains it from my perspective. Here’s a breakdown of why you cannot
>   mix repositories such as this, and the problems you run into.
>
> ---
>
> ### Problem 1: Debian / Ubuntu / NGINX PPAs (maintained by yours truly) have flavors; nginx upstream does not.
>
> And by flavors, I mean `nginx-light`, `nginx-full`, `nginx-extras`,
>   `nginx-naxsi` (up until 1.6.2-2), and `nginx-core` (Ubuntu only, since
>   Ubuntu 14.04). Each of these flavors contains a different set of
>   modules, based on demand originating in Debian or the community (and
>   ultimately implemented in Debian). I will not go into the differences
>   here, however you can go to here and read my answer to the question
>   for more details.
>
> As a result of how NGINX modules are currently incorporated into the
>   program’s binaries, it is absolutely critical to separate out the
>   configuration files and default sample files and locations so that you
>   can switch between flavors (and upgrade between versions between
>   Ubuntu/Debian/PPAs) without issues and conflict between configuration
>   files. This requires the introduction of a package called
>   `nginx-common` – a package which contains files and other items that
>   are common to all versions of the nginx flavors in those versions of
>   the source package. This `nginx-common` is wholly the brainchild of
>   Debian’s work, and inherited in Ubuntu and the PPAs I maintain.
>
> The problem is: NGINX upstream does not ship ‘flavors’. They enable
>   all the default modules that are shipped in the nginx upstream ‘core’
>   code, and do not include any third party modules, nor do they
>   discriminate the modules to enable (to make ‘light’ builds, or ‘full’
>   builds). As such, the nginx upstream package is a single solitary
>   ‘nginx’ package. It does not separate out configuration files, nor
>   does it separate out the binaries.
>
> ---
>
> ### Problem 2: NGINX upstream doesn’t have third party modules.
>
> Now, I know what you’re thinking: “Why would Debian/Ubuntu include
>   third-party modules in the packaging?” Turns out, in Debian, the
>   demand for such ‘third party extensions’ was so high, that they
>   decided to include the modules. Such modules include the `nginx-lua`
>   module, the `nginx-perl` module, and even the NAXSI modules for NGINX
>   (which were in `nginx-naxsi` up until 1.6.2-2).
>
> The problem: These are third party modules, maintained separately from
>   the NGINX code base itself. They’re shipped as part of some of
>   Debian’s packages due to demand, but they in and of themselves can
>   cause packaging issues and conflicts, to the point where it requires
>   updating the modules’ code with each new release to fix issues in
>   those modules. This in and of itself lends to ‘maintainability’
>   problems. This is why the `nginx-naxsi` flavor was dropped from NGINX
>   in Debian and Ubuntu as of package version/revision 1.6.2-2. To fix
>   even simple bugs in the `nginx-naxsi` flavor (and its related
>   packages), the entire NAXSI module needed to be removed and replaced
>   with the latest upstream revisions of the code and plugin. This means
>   that to even fix bugs in how the NAXSI rules were handled (in order to
>   match the actual rule formats that needed to be in place for
>   whitelists and such), you’d have to do a replace of the entire NAXSI
>   module in the `nginx-naxsi` flavor. In Ubuntu, this would break the
>   ‘Stable Release Update’ in that new features would be added to the
>   package that could break things, old features could be removed, and it
>   would go beyond the ‘nitpick fix’ that’d be needed for a Stable
>   Release Update, such that the system would never be fixed.
>
> As a result, third party modules have to be maintained and updated
>   with almost every code update from NGINX upstream. For NGINX Mainline,
>   the Lua module needed to be updated three times for build failure
>   fixes in the PPAs. Since a lot of these third party modules (such as
>   NAXSI or Lua) are in demand by the community, but not available in the
>   NGINX Upstream repository (or in the case of the NAXSI release, even
>   the PPAs nowadays), you should not mix repositories, as you will lose
>   those modules, or lose some of the modules and gain others.
>
> <sup>-- Author: Thomas Ward; Site: http://dark-net.net/; License: [Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/)</sup>

Comment: This is the contents of my sources.list I'm not manually selecting any versions http://pastebin.com/raw/MSYUjpUf

Comment: @GreenGiant Check all your `*.list` files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` as well.  Also, include the output of `apt-cache policy nginx` as an edit to your question.